# Unable to refer to js array in one js file from another js file

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I need to refer to the arrays I create in a.js and use the arrays in the b.js. The arrays are globe inside a.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
categoryarray = [];
productarray = [];
```

And in the html file I have this

```
<script src="a.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="b.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But when I use array in b.js, the console reports that the arrays are not defined. Below is the whole content of my b.js, I have a practically same for loop in a.js, so that part should be correct. Something outside it should be wrong.

```
   ;(function($) {
      for(var k=0;k<categoryarray.length;k++){
        if(categoryarray[k][0]!==""){
          $('.tree').append('<li id="Cate_' + k + '">'+categoryarray[k][1]+'</li>');
          for(var l=0;l<productarray.length;l++){
            if(categoryarray[k][0]==productarray[l][2]){
              $('#Cate_' + k).append('<ul id="Pro_' + l + '"></ul>');
              $('#Pro_' + l).append("<li>"+productarray[l][1]+"</li>");
                    }
                }
            }
        }   

   })(jQuery);
```

Can anyone help me figure out what's wrong? many thanks!

Comment: "The arrays are globe inside a.js" If they're are **inside**, they can't be **global**. PS. ES6 has been out for THREE years. jQuery has invented TWELVE years ago and was no longer in the mainstream as of perhaps FIVE years ago. For better productivity, you really should update your skills.

Comment: @torazaburo Thank you torazaburo! Its good to know! I tried put the array in html file ahead of the declaration of two js file. Console reported nothing which is good, but the b,js yields nothing.

Answer (score 0):

> $(document).ready(function () {
>   categoryarray = [];
>   productarray = [];}

try

> categoryarray = [];
>   productarray = [];

Comment: Hi jin! It seems not working. and I forgot mentioning that this two arrays store the data from two xml files readying using ajax. So "$(document).ready(function ()" might be necessary.

Comment: add more details to your answer